# R markov chain package, is possible to set the coordinates and size of the nodes?

Tags: r, plot, chain, markov

I'm working with R in some biology-behavioural problems, and I have a transition matrix which I want to plot in a certain way.

I'm using the `markovchain` package, which makes easy the visualization.

This is a test-code and it's output.

```
> a<-array(0.25,dim = c(4,4))
> markov<-new("markovchain",transitionMatrix=a,states=c("a","b","c","d"), name="test")
> markov
test 
 A  4 - dimensional discrete Markov Chain defined by the following states: 
 a, b, c, d 
 The transition matrix  (by rows)  is defined as follows: 
 a    b    c    d
 a 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
 b 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
 c 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
 d 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25

 > plot(markov)
```

[image: Plot Output]

The thing is, I would like to set the coordinates of the graph nodes to place them in a 2D grid or something like that, and also to set the size of the nodes. 
I know that this package works with `S4`, but I'm not really familiar with it and don't know if there are any arguments that would be useful to me.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
layout <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
# [2,]    0    1
# [3,]    1    1
# [4,]    1    0

plot(markov, vertex.size = 25, layout = layout)
```

The `layout` is a matrix of two columns. Each row contains coordinates per node. With `vertex.size`, you can adjust the size of the nodes. Note that `markovchain` package benefits from the `igraph` package to do so.

[image]

With these layouts

```
layout <- matrix(c(4,-2,7,2,8,8,8,-4), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    4   -2
# [2,]    7    2
# [3,]    8    8
# [4,]    8   -4

plot(markov, vertex.size = 25, layout = layout)
```

You would have this:

[image]