# How to expand a markov probability plot in R?

Tags: r, markov-chains, markov

I am trying to turn a matrix into a probability plot using R. I have done this before, but this particular set of data is contained in an 8x8 matrix, so it is fairly large and in turn contains a lot of arrows. In consequence, the arrows all overlap each other, and it is very hard to read. My code so far after inputting the matrix

```
 library( markovchain )
 transition.matrix <- new( "markovchain", transitionMatrix = transition.matrix ) 

 plot( transition.matrix  )
```

which gives me [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwqQt.png).
 Is there any way to spread the cases apart so the arrows aren't on top of one another? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can provide a `layout` matrix to the `plot` command which lets you specify the position of the nodes; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205378/r-markov-chain-package-is-possible-to-set-the-coordinates-and-size-of-the-nodes) for a nice example.

Comment: You could provide the transition matrix to help you solve the problem.